# I want to remove the `active` class on the button which was previously clicked using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with a problem. I'm adding `active` classes to the pagination button which is clicked. When I click another link I want to remove the `active` class on the link that was previously clicked.

Any ideas?

html:

```
    <ul class="pagination">
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="active">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    </ul>
```

javascript:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination li');

for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        showPage((i + 1),students);  
        buttons[i].firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'active')
    });
}
```

Comment: It is weird to modify class using the attribute. Typically if you want to set it to a specific string you use `className`, and to add or remove individual classes use `classList` in modern browsers (I believe a subset of browsers that support let and const).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the active button and remove the class:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination li');

for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        showPage((i + 1),students);  

        // Add these two lines: 
        const active = document.querySelector('.pagination li a.active');
        if ( active ) 
            active.className = '';

        // Updated to use className
        buttons[i].firstElementChild.className = 'active';
    });
}
```

Comment: This approach removes all the css classes applied to the element, right?

Comment: @SarathChandra Yes, it does. The way the OP sets it also removes all classes before setting `active` (`.setAttribute('class', 'active')`), so I can be sure that there only is one class.

Comment: @Paulpro I tried it this way, but it does not work. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null`

Comment: @Jakwakwa Good catch, it would fail on the first click since there is no active element yet to remove the class from. I added an if statement safeguard so that it only tries to remove the class if there is an element to remove it from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there'll be **only one** element with the `active` class, you can do this:

```
var activeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
if(typeof(activeElement) != "undefined"){
  activeElement.classList.remove("active");
}
```

In case there is more than one element with the `active` class, only the first element will be modified.

Comment: `pagelinks.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`

Comment: You are getting this because there is no element with the class `active`. Our assumption is that there will be exactly one element with the class `active`.

Comment: Or could it be because your browser doesn't support `classlist`? Which browser are you using, btw?